# XSLT - Preventing non-defined element from being referenced

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Let's say for example I have an XML file for describing a meeting in which, at the end, there's a vote happening and I have it defined like this:

```
<meeting>
    <members>
        <member id="A"/>
        <member id="B"/>
    </members>
    <vote>
        <option1>
            <voting_member idref="A"/>
        </option1>
        <option2>
            <voting_member idref="B"/>
        </option2>
    </vote>
</meeting>
```

In XSL, how can I define a validation that prevents for example a member with idref="C" from voting if he's not defined inside ?

So far I came up with a workaround that counts the members in the list and the members in the vote and gives a warning the those counts do not match:

```
<xsl:if test="count(meeting/members)!=sum(count(meeting/vote/option1),count(meeting/vote/option2))"> Warning: mismatch </xsl:if>
```

But I need to verify the IDs itself in order to prevent situations where a member that is not defined in the meeting is allowed to vote, how do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
<xsl:if test="meeting/vote/option1/@idref!=meeting/members/member/@id">
    Warning
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct, as `@idref` is an attribute on `voting_member` and not `option1`? Perhaps you can edit your question to show the case where "C" is present as an `idref` but is not a member, along with the output you expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve cross-references is to use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** - for example:

**XML**

```
<meeting>
    <members>
        <member id="A"/>
        <member id="B"/>
    </members>
    <vote>
        <option1>
            <voting_member idref="A"/>
        </option1>
        <option2>
            <voting_member idref="B"/>
        </option2>
        <option3>
            <voting_member idref="C"/>
        </option3>
    </vote>
</meeting>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="member" match="member" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/meeting">
    <root>
        <xsl:variable name="non-members" select="vote/*/voting_member[not(key('member', @idref))]" />
        <xsl:if test="$non-members">
            <message>
                <xsl:text>WARNING: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($non-members)"/>
                <xsl:text> non-members are listed as having voted.</xsl:text>
            </message>
        </xsl:if>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <message>WARNING: 1 non-members are listed as having voted.</message>
</root>
```